# Locally Administered MAC addresses for WLAN ports in brctl

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, wlan

I am exploring Linux network stack by investigating outputs of various utilities on my home-grade router. My question is related to bridging. When I check the output of "brctl showmacs br0", it gives me the following output.

```
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer
1     18:28:61:f2:e9:b0       yes                0.00
6     18:28:61:f2:e9:b2       yes                0.00
5     18:28:61:f2:e9:b3       yes                0.00
6     1a:28:61:f2:e9:b2       no                 1.98
5     1a:28:61:f2:e9:b3       no                 2.48
6     64:b0:a6:cc:47:e8       no                31.17
5     88:e9:fe:79:2e:29       no                 0.10
5     8c:f5:a3:f6:a1:25       no                11.13
5     ac:bc:32:b1:53:ef       no                 0.10
5     f4:0f:24:27:df:ec       no                 0.10
```

For every wlan port (5 and 6 in my case) there exist both a local address and a non-local address which have the same mac addresses, only differing in "Universally/Locally Administered" bit.

1. Why is this the case? Is there specific reason for this?
2. Is this managed by Linux network stack or configured by device vendors?
3. Is there any case similar to these, but applies to ethernet interfaces as well?

If answers would be long, I really appreciate if you can suggest me relevant resources such as books or websites.